Estimating Helicopter Altitude Above Me Based on Webcam Triangulation?
I believe I have police helicopters that like to buzz around at altitudes of about 500', in a town-like area.  If this happened once a day, it wouldn't be a big deal, but it happens more like once an hour. (yes, I am a pilot myself, so I am generally aviation friendly, and I am not anti-police, either, but this is a bit too much.  they ought to be able to climb to 1000' or higher.  there are people on the ground, too.)
unfortunately, they also don't seem to have their ADSB switched on.  I can't even complain, because I can't accurately report altitude.  what I need is a program that can spot an object, presumably with two webcams, and triangulate a moving object.  I know it's a long shot that such a device or program exists, but if it does, I would love to find out about it.  if you are aware of one, please post.
PS: Some comments asked why I bother.  I called to complain to the police, but they politely deny that their copters are regularly flying this low.  I know it's hard to guess altitude, but I think I know when a helicopter flies within 300' of my house at less than 500'.  Can I stop them?  No.  Do I want to reduce helicopter flights?  No!  We need them.  I am just trying to induce them nicely to become more reasonable.  If not, our concilwoman may be able to complain with some data.

Webcams exist.  Sextants exist.  Otherwise I doubt something as specific as you are asking for is readily available.  Likely your question might be closed as a resource question, or off topic, but I'd consider non-aviation avenues for an answer.  e.g. surveyor equipment, laser levels for construction, etc.  P.S. you can complain, you will just be lacking hard evidence.

Also, from a photo of the helicopter over something like a building of known elevation and dimensions it is possible to do the measure and so math with angles to determine height.

If you want to complain, just call them and complain. What they're doing is legal so what's the point of collecting evidence?

Who are you attempting to complain to that requires exact altitudes? The FAA's low flying aircraft reporting only requires that you give an altitude estimate and explain how you estimated it (and photos are helpful here). But just FYI, if you're attempting to gather evidence that they're flying below 500' in a populated area so you can make a complaint to the FAA, realize that helicopters are exempt from that rule provided they don't endanger anyone on the ground.

Knowing the heli type and thus the rotor diameter, a camera lens of known field of view gives you the distance to the heli.  But height above ground isn't that trivial.

@CamilleGoudeseune: as you said, distance is easy to calculate, but you miss that angle is also very easy, you can do with nearly any phone (inclination), so you can get altitude.

@GiacomoCatenazzi, smart!  Please post our two comments as another answer, for when the local terrain is flat.

@CamilleGoudeseune: it will take too much time (so maybe later). It doesn't depend on flat terrain: it work very well on mountain: all star-tracking application work so, but I used standard apps to prepare myself for a solar eclipse (to check if mountains will hide sun too early). -- probably a different way to "triangulate" as the OP may have think, but by having fixed size object (and large), distance is easier to calculate as std method (as you wrote)

Webcam triangulation is actually much more difficult than you would think. Webcams are not designed to measure angles, so the only way I could think of making that sort of system work would be to position two or three webcams, then have an aircraft fly through the area several times. If you were able to feed very accurate position and time data (synchronized to the webcam recording time) you could use machine learning to train the cameras to determine position and height to a reasonable degree of certainty. That's a lot of work and requires you to have that position data.
Otherwise you would have to make cameras which had angle lines painted on the webcam surface, then develop a system to recognize those lines. That's also a lot of work.
A much easier option would be to get a cheap laser rangefinder and put it on a tripod where you can measure the angle above the horizon. As long as the tripod is on a level base if you know the distance to the target and the angle above the horizon you can use simple right triangle trigonometry, where height above the ground would be the hypotenuse times sin(angle).
So H = Range * sin(angle above the horizon)
However, there are considerations here. There will be a bit of inaccuracy inherent in trying to range find and get the angle of a moving object, if you have a hovering chopper that's easier. Also, the height above the ground where you are may be different from the height above ground where the helicopter is.
There's also the fact that pointing lasers at aircraft, even one that is in the infrared like a rangefinder, could get you in trouble even if it isn't strictly illegal. In any case the police almost certainly have permission to fly below 500ft if they are in fact doing so, in which case it's hard to see what you'd accomplish.

Unless the chopper is quite close it will be difficult to get an accurate measurement. Assume it's at 500 feet AGL 1nm away. The actual angle is 4.7 degrees. If your angle measurement is off by only a degree that gives you about 100 feet of error in the altitude estimate.

Please don't shoot a laser, any laser, at an aircraft, ever.

Laser rangefinders are invisible and aren't going to damage anyone's eyes @RalphJ, however I agree it's not what should be done.

Perhaps one could use automotive radar equipment for this task

@RalphJ Laser rangefinders are invisible and, more importantly, dim enough that they can't damage your eye even from point blank range. Pointing them at aircraft is perfectly safe and as far as I can tell even legal.

Actually,webcams are perfectly capable of measuring angles (that's the only thing they can do;what they can't measure is distances). There's a unique mapping of every direction around the lens axis to a pixel coordinate. With ideal optics it's just simple linear algebra, various aberrations make it more complicated,but still feasible to model accurately. No need for machine learning at all (that would normally be used to identify objects in the picture,but that part OP does not need to automate).

it seems like the obvious goto solution would indeed be a rangefinder, such as those used for golf (905nm Class 1 Laser, Laser output <5mw).  they even give altitude.  alas, I really wish I knew whether this is both legal and reasonable.  Even if it is legal, I wouldn't want to annoy the copters.  However, if it is legal and invisible to them, this would be a great solution.
